# Задано список слов. Вывести все гласные буквы, которые не входят ни в какое из слов. Использовать множества)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str_data=input("Enter string: ")
print("Input data:", str_data)
str_1='aeoyui'
set1=set()
set2=set()
for i in range(len(str_data)):
    if str_data[i] in str_1:
        set2.add(str_data[i])
    else:
       set1.add(str_data[i])

print(" Result:", set1)
```

Не могу понять как вывести те гласные буквы, которые не являются в слове, поправьте пожалуйста и если можно объясните)Буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно найти гласные, которые не входят ни в одно слово предложения, значит, нужно из множества гласных убрать все буквы, которые входят в строку:

```
str_data=input("Enter string: ")
print("Input data:", str_data)

vowel='aeoyui'

result = set(vowel) - set(str_data)
print("Result:", result)
```

Результат:

```
Enter string: hello, world, hah
Input data: hello, world, hah
Result: {'i', 'y', 'u'}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое:)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста ;)

Comment: А можно еще вопрос?

Comment: Да, разумеется, можно

Comment: А как найти букву которая больше раз входит и количество вхождений

Comment: Просто я делал циклом

Comment: и не вишло можеш как то не правильно делаю цикл

Comment: @AndrijMatviiv, https://repl.it/@Eugene51675/MaxLetters

Comment: Большое спасибо:)

Comment: @Евгений `str_1` плохое название для переменной, хорошо бы использовать что-то "говорящее" всё-таки )

Comment: @CrazyElf ответ с сохранением изначального посыла автора вопроса =) В своих проектах называю переменные по-своему. Впрочем, вы правы, ответы принадлежат сообществу, и надо бы сделать его более общим. Сейчас попровлю

Answer (score 0):

Положите гласные в сет. Если встретили гласную - удаляйте её из сета. Что останется - выводите.

```
s = 'abcy ooo'
vowelset = set('aeoyui')
for c in s:
    if c in vowelset:
        vowelset.remove(c)
print(vowelset)

>>> {'e', 'i', 'u'}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое:)